# Incomplete Object in child method call

Tags: php, codeigniter

Confusing problem and couldn't come up with a good title, but I'll explain as best I can.

I am using CodeIgniter, and utilizing the `get_instance()` function to have access to the CI super object in some classes.  I have a parent class that calls the super object

```
abstract class parent{

/**
 * properties
 */
protected $CI;

/**
 * constructor
 */
public function __construct(){
    $this->CI =& get_instance();
}
```

and many child classes

```
class child extends parent{

    public function __construct(){
        //parent
        parent::__construct();

        print_r($this->CI);
    }

    public function doSomething(){
        print_r($this->CI);
    }
}
```

when printed in the `child` constructor the CI object is fine. when printed in the `child` `doSomething()` method, I get an Incomplete Class Object.

EDIT:

I believe I've identified the problem somewhat. When CI creates its Super Object is uses the controller class. In the cases where my problem arises, this is the `Login` controller. Apparently that name is carrying over when I assign by reference, and then if I'm no longer in my `Login` controller, it has the issue with the incomplete class. I can "*fix*" it by re-calling the `get_instance()` function when it's being used, but that isn't a great solution. Any ideas?

Comment: Typically, you'll get this situation when an object has been serialised in $_SESSION, and is restored via session_start() before the original class definition file for the object has been loaded

Comment: yes. i have autoloading setup though, and this particular instance is not using `$_SESSION`. the thing that is confusing is that it's fine in the child constructor, but not the child method.

Comment: But if the autoloader is registered __after__ your session_start(), then it can still create problems.... I had exactly the same issue with storing a User object in session in Laravel, when the User object was extended from a base object, but it wasn't a problem if I didn't have that inheritence

Comment: Is this causing a problem for you? I've done this sort of thing before but never run into any issues - of course, I've never thought to `print_r` the CI object :-)

Comment: my `session_start` is setup as a precontroller hook, and my autoloading is done in my `config.php` file, which is handled quite early in the bootstrap

Comment: this is something relatively new I'm doing, in an attempt to do Lazy Loading. it's weird because it works in many other places, but not in this one particular instance.

Answer (score 0):

So after a lot of looking it seems I found the answer in the PHP manual

```
Warning
You can't use references in session variables as there is no feasible way to restore a reference to another variable.
```

This is why it works perfectly fine in many places, but if I access it from a `$_SESSION` variable, like for my logged in user, I get the error. It stores the `get_instance()` at the time the `$_SESSION` variable was created, not the reference, like I need.

Thanks for the comments.